# rendering different templates in angular2

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-routing

I have just started using `angular2` and I am facing some situation to organize my logic. I am actually refactoring `backend theme` that consists of the two main components i.e `login view` that is supposed to appear on page load and `main dashboard` that will appear on successful login. I have no problem with the `main dashboard` template because i have refactored all the code its working fine. However the main problem is with the `login` module because `dashboard` consist of the `sidebar`, `header` and `maincontent` area.  My real problem is that how do I exclude `sidebar`, `header` on loading the login page which will going to be the startpoint of my app.  To be more precise, can i use the layout for the `login module` which is independent to the `dashboard module`? Here is my current code for the dashboard.
I would really appreciate if anyone could help me structure this app in proper way.

P.S I am using `node` as a backend

`index.html`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>


    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <base  href="/">
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app/main').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <parent>
       Loading...
    </parent>

    <!-- START SCRIPTS -->
        <!-- START PLUGINS -->

  </body>
</html>
```

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { AuthComponent } from './auth/auth.component';
import { ListComponent } from './blogs/list.component';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, AuxRoute} from '@angular/router-deprecated';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl:'app/main.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, HeaderComponent, SidebarComponent, AuthComponent]
})


@RouteConfig([
        { path: '/list', name: 'BlogList', component: ListComponent}

])


export class AppComponent { 
     constructor(private _router: Router , private _zone:NgZone){}
}
```

`main.ts`

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
bootstrap(AppComponent,[ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
import {NgZone, enableProdMode} from '@angular/core'
```

`main.html`

```
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="page-sidebar">
        <mysidebar>
        </mysidebar>
    </div>
    <div class="page-content">
        <myheader>
        </myheader>
        <!-- PAGE CONTENT WRAPPER -->
        <div class="page-content-wrap">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using a `Service`

```
export class AppComponentService {

    public showSidebar : boolean = true;
    public showHeader : boolean = true; 

}
```

If you add this service during `bootstrap`:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent,[ROUTER_PROVIDERS, AppComponentService ]);
```

You can inject this into your AppComponent:

```
export class AppComponent { 
     constructor(
          private _router: Router, 
          private _zone:NgZone, 
          private _appService: AppComponentService
     ){}
}
```

And change your template to:

```
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="page-sidebar">
        <mysidebar *ngIf="_appService.showSidebar">
        </mysidebar>
    </div>
    <div class="page-content">
        <myheader *ngIf="_appService.showHeader">
        </myheader>
        <!-- PAGE CONTENT WRAPPER -->
        <div class="page-content-wrap">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Within your `LoginComponent` you can inject the same singleton service, and play with it on `routerOnActivate` and `routerOnDeactivate`:

```
export class LoginComponent {

    constructor(private _appService: AppComponentService){}

    routerOnActivate() : void {
        this._appService.showSidebar = false;
        this._appService.showHeader = false;
    }

    routerOnDeactivate() : void {
        this._appService.showSidebar = true;
        this._appService.showHeader = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't I use multiple layouts in this case? For e.g if its a `login`, use this layout, else use this layout.. If it can be done, how i can achieve it?

Comment: It can be done a little. But it's not perfect. You have to put it in one template, but switch it using `*ngIf`